# Parsing a Reddit search result with BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Using Python/BeautifulSoup, I'm trying to get the post title and URL from every result returned on Reddit.

Below is part of my code that retrieves all Reddit search results.

```
url = 'https://www.reddit.com/search/?q=test'
r = s.get(url, headers=headers_Get)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
results = soup.find_all('a', attrs={'data-click-id':'body'})
for result in results:
    print(result.prettify())
    title_post = result.find('h3').text
    url_post = result.find('a')['href']
```

`soup.find_all('a', attrs={'data-click-id':'body'})` appears to return a list of all search results. This is working as I'm expecting / hoping.

by doing `print(result)`, I can validate that it is returning what I need. Below is the result of `print(result.prettify())`:

```
<a class="SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z _2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE" data-click-id="body" href="/r/Cricket/comments/kunmyt/match_thread_3rd_test_australia_v_india_day_5/">
<div class="_2SdHzo12ISmrC8H86TgSCp _1zpZYP8cFNLfLDexPY65Y7" style="--posttitletextcolor:#222222">
<h3 class="_eYtD2XCVieq6emjKBH3m">
<span style="font-weight:normal">Match Thread: 3rd
<em style="font-weight:700">Test
</em>- Australia v India, Day 5
</span>
</h3>
</div>
</a>
```

`title_post = result.find('h3').text` extracts the title associated with the comment or post. It is working as expected / hoped.

The problem that I have is with retrieving the address of the post (see href=):

```
<a class="SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z _2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE" data-click-id="body" href="/r/Cricket/comments/kunmyt/match_thread_3rd_test_australia_v_india_day_5/">
```

The line `url_post = result.find('a')['href']` returns an error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

If I could use the "result" as a string, then I could just look for href within it. Something like:

```
loc = result.text.find('href=')
print(result.text[loc:])
```

Obviously, this won't work:
`result.text` does not return the HTML code, but just the string "Match Thread: 3rd Test - Australia v India, Day 5"

Question 1:
Is there a way to return only the href="" component?

Question 2:
Is there a way to convert the soup object "result" into plain text while keeping the HTML components? If it was possible, then I'd have an easy workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `href` is already in the [`.attrs`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) of `result`:

```
>>> for result in results:
...     print(result.attrs)
...
{'data-click-id': 'body', 'class': ['SQnoC3ObvgnGjWt90zD9Z', '_2INHSNB8V5eaWp4P0rY_mE'], 'href': '/r/Cricket/comments/kunmyt/match_thread_3rd_test_australia_v_india_day_5/'}
...
```

so don't call the `.find()` method, instead access the `href` value using the `[key]` notation (like a dictionary).

In your example:

```
for result in results:
    url_post = result["href"]
    print(url_post)
```

Output:

```
/r/Cricket/comments/kunmyt/match_thread_3rd_test_australia_v_india_day_5/
/r/Cricket/comments/ku008u/match_thread_3rd_test_australia_v_india_day_4/
/r/Cricket/comments/ktcg7n/match_thread_3rd_test_australia_v_india_day_3/
...
```

Comment: Thank you. @MendelG, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PRAW: The Python Reddit API Wrapper` for their API, which is much easier to use than parsing from the webpages. You are obviously not able to access their randomly generated class names.

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out.